# Style button with :before don`t work

Tags: html, wordpress, css, blogger

I try to make my header like this wordpress this: https://boardwalkdemo.wordpress.com/

But something isn't right. My toggle button `:before` code is not show properly.

I can see my progress live at http://detelin-markov.blogspot.com/

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *.sidebar-toggle::before* you should add the font-family which is FontAweSome and your content is not recognized by the font.

Here is an example:

```
.sidebar-toggle::before {
   content: "\f039";
   height: 24px;
   width: 16px;
   color: inherit;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 24px;
   font-family: 'FontAweSome';
}
```